# What is better : Disabling sub-categories or auto resetting the filters

Tags: navigation, e-commerce, filter, desktop-application

I am working enhancing UX for filters on our eCommerce (desktop site). The navigation structure is broken into Categories and further sub categories. Filters can be applied at each level (categories & sub categories). My question is what is better approach when user is on Categories and applies filters

1. To  disables some of the sub-categories in the navigation because all of the products under these (disabled sub categories) got filtered out or
2. Keep all the sub categories active, but if user goes to a specific sub- category that doesn't have any products matching to the filter applied, then auto reset the filter.

Comment: With either option, do you envision all subcategories being visible at all times? Can users choose more than one category at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Option #1 would be your best choice.

Disabling sub-categories in response to category selection would allow the user to quickly see how their category choice effects the available sub-categories.

In the example below, if I am ultimately looking for results in sub-category "Five" (which is currently disabled / greyed out), the interface suggests that I should try category "One".

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzUX9E.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Automatically disabling sub-category options with no results would save the user a significant amount of time and effort as they would not need to select the sub-category to see that there are no results.

It is unlikely that the user would expect that selecting a sub-category would clear their selection(s), so I would advise against option #2. An auto-reset could cause a high level of user frustration. You would be asking them to start over before they knew that something was wrong.